# Опустить скролл после загрузки в див данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

есть блок с сообщениями

```
<ul class="chat--messages__wrapper" v-if="messages.length > 0" ref="msg_wrapper">
    <li class="chat--messages__item" v-bind:class="{ user: message.user_id === userAuth.id }" v-for="(message,index) in messages">
        <div class="chat--user__image" v-bind:style='{ backgroundImage: `url("/storage/${message.avatar}")` }'></div>
        <div class="chat--user__data">
            <p class="last--massage" v-html="message.replay"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

как после загрузки из метода

```
selectUser(id){
                axios.post('/profile/dialogs/messages',{
                    dialog_id: id,
                    offset: this.offset,
                    limit: this.limit
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.messages = response.data.messages;
                        this.dialog.like = response.data.like;
                        this.dialog.favorite = response.data.favorite;
                        this.dialog.ignore = response.data.ignore;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
```

опустить скролл блока `.chat--messages__wrapper` вниз?

Comment: Блок изначально существует, просто добавляются в него данные? Покажите разметку html

Comment: Добавил в вопросе

Comment: @Alslero на вскидку есть 2 варианта. Jquery подойдёт?

Comment: да, конечно подойдет

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```html
<div id="div" style="height: 100px; overflow-x: scroll;">
    <div style="height: 2000px; background: linear-gradient(rgb(17, 142, 199) 0%, rgb(215, 238, 248));">
      div
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      let div = document.getElementById("div")
      div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight
    }, 1000)
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Хотел бы дополнить немного ответ Alexandra Lonberga
Чтобы не использовать `setTimeout`, который постоянно будет запускать проверку, можно использовать библиотеку (А остальное по логике Александра(Не стал копи пастить))

```js
  /**
     * Copyright Marc J. Schmidt. See the LICENSE file at the top-level
     * directory of this distribution and at
     * https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries/blob/master/LICENSE.
     */

    (function(root, factory) {
        if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
            define(factory);
        } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
            module.exports = factory();
        } else {
            root.ResizeSensor = factory();
        }
    }(this, function() {

        // Make sure it does not throw in a SSR (Server Side Rendering) situation
        if (typeof window === "undefined") {
            return null;
        }
        // Only used for the dirty checking, so the event callback count is limited to max 1 call per fps per sensor.
        // In combination with the event based resize sensor this saves cpu time, because the sensor is too fast and
        // would generate too many unnecessary events.
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(fn) {
                return window.setTimeout(fn, 20);
            };

        /**
         * Iterate over each of the provided element(s).
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement|HTMLElement[]} elements
         * @param {Function}                  callback
         */
        function forEachElement(elements, callback) {
            var elementsType = Object.prototype.toString.call(elements);
            var isCollectionTyped = ('[object Array]' === elementsType ||
                ('[object NodeList]' === elementsType) ||
                ('[object HTMLCollection]' === elementsType) ||
                ('[object Object]' === elementsType) ||
                ('undefined' !== typeof jQuery && elements instanceof jQuery) //jquery
                ||
                ('undefined' !== typeof Elements && elements instanceof Elements) //mootools
            );
            var i = 0,
                j = elements.length;
            if (isCollectionTyped) {
                for (; i < j; i++) {
                    callback(elements[i]);
                }
            } else {
                callback(elements);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Class for dimension change detection.
         *
         * @param {Element|Element[]|Elements|jQuery} element
         * @param {Function} callback
         *
         * @constructor
         */
        var ResizeSensor = function(element, callback) {
            /**
             *
             * @constructor
             */
            function EventQueue() {
                var q = [];
                this.add = function(ev) {
                    q.push(ev);
                };

                var i, j;
                this.call = function() {
                    for (i = 0, j = q.length; i < j; i++) {
                        q[i].call();
                    }
                };

                this.remove = function(ev) {
                    var newQueue = [];
                    for (i = 0, j = q.length; i < j; i++) {
                        if (q[i] !== ev) newQueue.push(q[i]);
                    }
                    q = newQueue;
                }

                this.length = function() {
                    return q.length;
                }
            }

            /**
             *
             * @param {HTMLElement} element
             * @param {Function}    resized
             */
            function attachResizeEvent(element, resized) {
                if (!element) return;
                if (element.resizedAttached) {
                    element.resizedAttached.add(resized);
                    return;
                }

                element.resizedAttached = new EventQueue();
                element.resizedAttached.add(resized);

                element.resizeSensor = document.createElement('div');
                element.resizeSensor.className = 'resize-sensor';
                var style = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;';
                var styleChild = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s;';

                element.resizeSensor.style.cssText = style;
                element.resizeSensor.innerHTML =
                    '<div class="resize-sensor-expand" style="' + style + '">' +
                    '<div style="' + styleChild + '"></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="resize-sensor-shrink" style="' + style + '">' +
                    '<div style="' + styleChild + ' width: 200%; height: 200%"></div>' +
                    '</div>';
                element.appendChild(element.resizeSensor);

                if (element.resizeSensor.offsetParent !== element) {
                    element.style.position = 'relative';
                }

                var expand = element.resizeSensor.childNodes[0];
                var expandChild = expand.childNodes[0];
                var shrink = element.resizeSensor.childNodes[1];
                var dirty, rafId, newWidth, newHeight;
                var lastWidth = element.offsetWidth;
                var lastHeight = element.offsetHeight;

                var reset = function() {
                    expandChild.style.width = '100000px';
                    expandChild.style.height = '100000px';

                    expand.scrollLeft = 100000;
                    expand.scrollTop = 100000;

                    shrink.scrollLeft = 100000;
                    shrink.scrollTop = 100000;
                };

                reset();

                var onResized = function() {
                    rafId = 0;

                    if (!dirty) return;

                    lastWidth = newWidth;
                    lastHeight = newHeight;

                    if (element.resizedAttached) {
                        element.resizedAttached.call();
                    }
                };

                var onScroll = function() {
                    newWidth = element.offsetWidth;
                    newHeight = element.offsetHeight;
                    dirty = newWidth != lastWidth || newHeight != lastHeight;

                    if (dirty && !rafId) {
                        rafId = requestAnimationFrame(onResized);
                    }

                    reset();
                };

                var addEvent = function(el, name, cb) {
                    if (el.attachEvent) {
                        el.attachEvent('on' + name, cb);
                    } else {
                        el.addEventListener(name, cb);
                    }
                };

                addEvent(expand, 'scroll', onScroll);
                addEvent(shrink, 'scroll', onScroll);
            }

            forEachElement(element, function(elem) {
                attachResizeEvent(elem, callback);
            });

            this.detach = function(ev) {
                ResizeSensor.detach(element, ev);
            };
        };

        ResizeSensor.detach = function(element, ev) {
            forEachElement(element, function(elem) {
                if (!elem) return
                if (elem.resizedAttached && typeof ev == "function") {
                    elem.resizedAttached.remove(ev);
                    if (elem.resizedAttached.length()) return;
                }
                if (elem.resizeSensor) {
                    if (elem.contains(elem.resizeSensor)) {
                        elem.removeChild(elem.resizeSensor);
                    }
                    delete elem.resizeSensor;
                    delete elem.resizedAttached;
                }
            });
        };

        return ResizeSensor;

    }));
    $('#click').on('click', function () {
        $('#Test_DIV').append('<div class="nn">SomeNewlines</div>');
    });

    new ResizeSensor(jQuery('#Test_DIV'), function(){
        console.log('Размер div изменился');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=Test_DIV> Тут что-то; </div>
<button id="click">Тык</button>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` там, для визуализации примера. А скроллинг, автор вопроса будет вызывать обработчиком, после загрузки данных. Кроме того, я бы не использовал свой метод - это всего лишь пример. Реализация должна учитывать и плавную анимацию css, а тут двумя строчками примера не обойтись.